# Is there any Excel like but free software that is able to plot X-Y-Z 3d graphs

Tags: excel, plot, 3d

I want to plot a 3d graph from three columns representing x,y,z e.g.

```
x,y,z
1,1,0
1,0,1
01,1,0
```

Excel does not support this type of plot. Is there any free alternatives?

In a similar question, the author ended up with matplotlib: [3D Plotting from X, Y, Z Data, Excel or other Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881959/3d-plotting-from-x-y-z-data-excel-or-other-tools)

I know there are programming based software, like Gnuplot and matplotlib, can do this, but I want to use something with UI like excel to be able to mouse-select those columns to plot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a surface chart in Excel.

It is not possible to do it as you wish: You cannot just give the coordinates of each point with (x,y,z) and obtain the plot.

However, you can have the values z for each combinations of x and y, and you plot them.

You will just have to modify the name "series 1" "series 2" by the values of Y in order to obtain your 3D plot. see the graph [image: screen shot of 3D plot in Excel] .

In the attached image, I selected cells D3:F8 and did a surface chart. Then I right click on the graph and change "series 1" by "1", "series 2" by "2" ...

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excel does not support x-y-z data in the columns to plot 3d graphs.

Comment: It does, just need to use the following trick:
Plot the first two columns on a surface plot and then you change the name of the series by the values of the remaining column. This is the best proxy I found to do 3D plot.

Comment: Could you elaborate on changing the name of the series by the values of the remaining column? What exactly you need to do in excel?

Comment: for example you have
A 1 2 3 
B 4.5 6.7 9.2 
C 4 9 5 
(A B C are columns followed by their values, I still need to figure out how to show a table here... )


you select B and C values and make a surface chart. 

then you right click on the graph and choose 'select value'
on the series name (series 1,series 2, series 3) you click to modify, and you change the name by the values of column A, that is, "series 1" becomes "1", "series 2" becomes 2 and so on.